# Best practice to ensure that GCC assembler code is always located in first section?

Tags: gcc, assembly, makefile, linker, arm

I have some romable code consisting of one startup_code.s file and
several .c files. As the startup_code.o needs to be at offset 0x000000 of
the rom/flash I placed the object first in the makefile:

```
OBJ_FILE = \
    $(OBJECT_DIR)/startup_code.o \   <- Assembler startup
    $(OBJECT_DIR)/loader.o \
    $(OBJECT_DIR)/display.o \
.
.
```

This works so far but I now wanted to ensure that the location of the startup_code.o in rom is not dependent on the order in the makefile.

My first approach was changing the .s file:

```
.section .startup
Vector_Table:
   LDR      PC,=Reset_Handler
   .
   .
   .
```

and the memory.def file for the linker:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0xE0000000;
    .startup : { *(.startup) }
    .text : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss  : { *(.bss)  }
}
```

This did not work as startup_code.o was omitted in the binary output!
(Weirdly the assembler listing was correctly showing the startup_code first!)

I also tried to name the assembler obj file directly:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0xE0000000;
    .text : { startup_code.o(.text) }
    .text : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss  : { *(.bss)  }
}
```

**Problem**: The linker complains that it cannot find the
startup_code.o - though it exists.

In the end I succeeded with this def file:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0xE0000000;
    .text : { *(.startup) }
    .text : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss  : { *(.bss)  }
}
```

However I'm not sure if this is a recommendable approach and would like to ask how problem (locating startup code in the beginning) is solved "the right way" and if I have to take care of the linker to not throw the unreferenced code out?

Comment: From the sounds of things only the `.text`, `.data`, and `.bss` output sections are supported by your output format.

Comment: What happens if you leave the extension off: `.text : { startup_code(.text) }`

Answer (score -2):

something like

```
.section .startup
Vector_Table:
   LDR      PC,=Reset_Handler
   ....
```

---

```
MEMORY
{
    rom (rx) : ORIGIN = 0xE0000000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : {
        *(.startup) /* Startup code */
        *(.text*)   /* remaining code */
    } >rom
    .....
}
```

---

as an example you can reference libopencm3 for what you are looking.
[Memory information linker script](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3/blob/master/lib/stm32/f0/stm32f03xz6.ld)
[Generic linker script](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3/blob/master/lib/stm32/f0/libopencm3_stm32f0.ld)
[Vector handler](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3/blob/master/lib/cm3/vector.c#L40)

note: what i see from it is, it has described the memory layout (since there are multiple targets) and a generic file to commonize code. (though this is not relevant here, you can keep your both content in one file)

in this way you keep memory information and layout information seperate.
and easier to understand and manage.

Comment: You need to describe the solution in the answer itself. You shouldn't use links do the job for you.

Comment: @RossRidge added example.